# Author information on revision view overflows its content

Tags: bug, revisions-list

I just checked one random edit and saw this:

[image: Editor]

I think the reputation should be shorted to 889k. Anway that bronce badges are overflowing the box.

Comment: Yeah, that is not good. Let's downvote their posts to make some room for the badge numbers ....

Comment: Partial... It is a dub of one but not the other one. I'm not sure which option I should select. Since fixing the first bug would not fix the overflow I would guess

Comment: Actually it would fit exactly. I just checked it with the developer tools.

Comment: @rekire rewrite 889340 as 889K would save enough room to have everything in the box.

Comment: If it won't fit, shorten the badge count as well. 245, 3.5k, 3k

Comment: Too bad that we cannot downvote badges to make even some room ;-)